How to Use same Element over and over again
I have got an HTML Form in which there is a drop down list:
<select id="DWl1">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="C2C">C2C</option>
  <option value="Advance Search">Advance Search</option>
  <option value="EIV">EIV</option>
  <option value="EWS">EWS</option>
  <option value="PSU">PSU</option>
</select>

I have got to use the same drop down list over and over in multiple forms on the same page.
Currently I have created this list with multiple different IDs, like DWl1, Dwl2, DWl3 ect.
Is there a way that I can use this drop down list again and again without having to create so many different IDs?

Can you improve your question? I couldn't understand you.

Use a templating engine? Or a UI framework? Either of those makes this trivial. (the first is generally an include for the pulldown, the second is generally an import of the pulldown's component/fragment/whatevertheycallit)

What is the underlying mechanism that won't require `id' values for each list? Can you clarify how each of the multiple select elements with the same options is used - e.g. are they on different tabs of a single page app or something else again? Do they have to be synchronized etc. ?

Answers cannot be added as long at this questions is closed. You can skip the IDs for the select element and only use the name attribute (let's call it searchtype: <select name="searchtype">...). The value of the name attribute does not have to be unique. Now, you can refer to the form field by form01.searchtype where form01 is a reference to a form.


Create empty divs based on your id tags.
Add your select inside a <template> and add an id to it.
Call a method, that adds the select to different forms, whenever the page has loaded.
Loop through all your ids in 0).
Copy the content of the template via the id you set in 1)
Add an id to the first element (your select tag).
Get a reference to your container where you want to place your select element.
Append your copied select element as a child to your container.

Hit the Run Code Snippet button below, right-click one of the dropdowns, select Inspect, and see that each has the correct id.


const addSelects = () => {
  const selectIdArr = ['DWl1', 'DWl2', 'DWl3'];
  let selectElContainer;
  const selectTemplate = document.getElementById('select-template');
  
  for (const id of selectIdArr) { // 3
    const copiedSelect = selectTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);  // 4
    copiedSelect.firstElementChild.id = id; // 5
    
    selectElContainer = document.getElementById(id + '-container'); // 6
    
    selectElContainer.appendChild(copiedSelect);  // 7
  }
}

addSelects(); // 2
<template id="select-template">
  <select>
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="C2C">C2C </option>
    <option value="Advance Search">Advance Search</option>
    <option value="EIV">EIV</option>
    <option value="EWS">EWS</option>
    <option value="PSU">PSU</option>
  </select>
</template>

<form><div id="DWl1-container"></div></form>

<form><div id="DWl2-container"></div></form>

<form><div id="DWl3-container"></div></form>




It sounds like you want to make many similar lists, perhaps dynamically. I think template literals will come in handy here.
For example,


let name = "Alice";
let age = 30;
let message = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old.`;
console.log(message);
// Output: My name is Alice and I am 30 years old.



GO HERE for some handy documentation on template literals.
To get you started, I would try something like this:


let forms = 3 // Adjust the number of lists you need

for (i = 0; i < forms; i++) {
  formTemplate = ` 
<span><b>DIV ID = ${i}<b></span>
<select>
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
  < option value="C2C">C2C </option>
  <option value="Advance Search">Advance Search</option>
  <option value="EIV">EIV</option>
  <option value="EWS">EWS</option>
  <option value="PSU">PSU</option>
</select>`


  let newDiv = document.createElement('DIV')
  newDiv.innerHTML = formTemplate
  newDiv.id = `DWI${i}`
  document.querySelector('#forms').appendChild(newDiv)
}
<html>

<body>

  <div id="forms">

  </div>

</body>

</html>



